# Optaplanner logging won't work correctly running from RestEasy server

Tags: java, tomcat, optaplanner

I create RestEasy server which controls optaplanner. I sent requests to the server and that servers start optaplanner. When I start optaplanner from eclipse like normal application then logging works correctly, but when I run my server which starts optaplanner my logs looks like

```
2017-06-08 10:35:13,033 [123] INFO  VehicleRoutingSolution TMS_DATA has 1 depots, 20 vehicles and 70 customers with a search space of 10^25.
2017-06-08 10:35:13,034 [123] INFO  Imported: \\xxxx\xxxxx\xxx\xxxx.vrp
2017-06-08 10:35:13,740 [SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-1] INFO  Solving started: time spent (394), best score (70uninitialized/-42308000hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2017-06-08 10:35:13,916 [SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-1] INFO  Custom phase (0) ended: step total (1), time spent (570), best score (-42308000hard/0soft).
2017-06-08 10:35:16,157 [SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-1] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (1) ended: step total (50), time spent (2811), best score (-38400hard/-2911900soft).
2017-06-08 10:35:21,673 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  Terminating solver early.
2017-06-08 10:35:21,675 [SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-1] INFO  Local Search phase (2) ended: step total (8), time spent (8329), best score (-31200hard/-2911900soft).
2017-06-08 10:35:21,676 [SwingWorker-pool-8-thread-1] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (8330), best score (-31200hard/-2911900soft), average calculate count per second (1306), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
```

My project structure in eclipse looks like

[image: Optaplanner][image: RestEasyServer]

I added optaplanner to build path and to deployment assembly.

It looks like logback.xml level=-info but it is -debug.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d [%t] %-5p %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.optaplanner" level="${logback.level.org.optaplanner:-debug}"/>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I think that whole application can't find lockback.xml but after extract the .war on tomcat the file is present. Any idea how to bring back optaplanner logging?

Comment: Relates to this [Wildfly with OptaPlanner](
  http://optashift-employee-rostering-optashift-gdesmet-redhat-com.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/) question. Seems like the appservers ignore our logback configuration etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my fault, I include src/test/ to .war and in src/test is logback-test.xml and that file has priority before logback.xml. I found out that logback-test.xml has configured to level=-info